# Finding Distribution of N mutually independent random varibles

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2, ...,X_n$ be $n$ mutually independent random variables , each of which is uniformly distributed on the integers from 1 to k. Let $Y$ denote the minimum of the $X_i$'s. Find the distribution of $Y$.

The exercise suggests that I start by finding the expression for $P(Y \ge j)$ where $j$ is an integer in the appropriate range. Then, use the expression you get to find $P(Y=j)$.

I know the final answer for the distribution is

$$f(x)=\frac{(k-x+1)^n-(k-x)^n}{k^n}, \hspace{10mm} for \hspace{2mm} 1 \le x \le k$$

I know that the random variables are mutually exclusive and that a uniform distribution has to have a finite set of outcomes ${w_1, w_2,...,w_3}$ which have $P(x=w_j) = \frac{1}{k} \hspace{2mm} for \hspace{2mm} j=0,1,2,...k$

I do not see how they came to the distribution they gave for $P(Y=j)$

Comment: Did you try their hint of finding an expression for $P(Y\ge j)$?

Comment: No. I am confused as to how you combine the uniform distributions. I add them together I believe.

Comment: You use the fact that $P(Y\ge j) = P(X_1\ge j, X_2\ge j,\ldots,  X_n\ge j) = P(X\ge j)^n$ (which has nothing to do with the distribution other than the second equality that uses the fact that $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed. Then you use the fact that $X$ is uniform to compute $P(X\ge k).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(Y \ge j) &= P(\min{X_1, \ldots, X_n} \ge j) \\
&= P\left((X_1 \ge j) \,\cap\, \ldots \,\cap\, (X_n \ge j) \right) \qquad \text{If $min(a, b) > x$, then $a > x$ and $b > x$}\\
&= P(X_1 \ge j) \times \ldots \times P(X_n \ge j) \qquad \text{By independence} \\
&= \left(\frac{k - j + 1}{k}\right)^n
\end{align}

We immediately have $P(Y \ge j + 1) = \left(\frac{k - j}{k}\right)^n$. Subtracting, you have the desired result.

Note: The trick ``If $min(a, b) > x$, then $a > x$ and $b > x$'' is something you will always resort to when there is a min of random variables involved. Vice-versa for max.